# Profiles in React

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to figure out how to run a react application (created through [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/)) with different profiles.

That is, suppose I have several environments (local, dev, prod) and I have a fetch that refers to the backend (which is deployed on another server).

The backend has its own address for each environment. I need to somehow set global variables for different launches.

For example, in Springboot this can be done via application-"profile".properties.

I run the application through npm install -g serve & serve -s build. How to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When working with *create-react-app*, you can configure your app using environment variables.

It is explained in detail in the documentation here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

All environment variables need to be prefixed with `REACT_APP_`.

You can define profiles with different environment variables using *.env* files.

For example, to set an API URL in production, create a file *.env.production* with the following contents:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://my.beautiful.api/
```

…and as default (for local development), create a file *.env*:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3001/
```

- The environment variables from the *.env.production* file will be used when you build your project with `npm run build`
- The environment variables from the *.env* file will be used when you work on your project in local dev mode with `npm start`

Example for using the environment variable in your app's code:

```
fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The way i handle this case is by using package `react-native-config` and i have create .env file (.env.dev, .env.staging, .env.prod) and i have define some scripts in the package.json. I am using react-native init project though.
as below

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "sed -i '' 's/#import <RCTAnimation\\/RCTValueAnimatedNode.h>/#import \"RCTValueAnimatedNode.h\"/' ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/RCTNativeAnimatedNodesManager.h",
    "clean": "cd android && gradlew clean",
    "feature": "node scripts/createfeature.js",
    "component": "node scripts/createcomponent.js",
    "android": "cd android && gradlew app:assembleDebug && gradlew installDebug",
    "storybook": "storybook start -p 7007",
    "prestorybook": "rnstl",
    "android-dev": "SET ENVFILE=.env.dev && react-native run-android",
    "android-staging": "SET ENVFILE=.env.staging && react-native run-android",
    "android-prod": "SET ENVFILE=.env.prod && react-native run-android",
    "ios-dev": "ENVFILE=.env.dev react-native run-ios",
    "ios-staging": "ENVFILE=.env.staging react-native run-ios",
    "ios-prod": "ENVFILE=.env.prod react-native run-ios",
    "build-android-prod": "SET ENVFILE=.env.prod && cd android && gradlew assembleRelease"
  },
```