# ReactJS profiles

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, profile

I am trying to understand if it is possible to use profiles like Java Spring profiles on ReactJS.
I mean, in case I developed a dashboard for many different customers, and want a core code for all of them, and by demand of one of the customers, add the part he wants only for him (only him will see this). Is it possible to achieve this on ReactJS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Profiles in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557373/profiles-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to show users certain pages-components and allow them to navigate to certain routes.

1. You need authentication to distinguish between users with some roles "Backend server that generates the user's tokens and assign them roles or 3rd party service"
2. I suggest you using Redux with your react app, and once the user log-in you dispatch an action with the current user role
3. Once you dispatched the action all the components that connected to redux will be notified and your conditions that show/hide things will work properly

Comment: Yes, I think I will try it if it turns out that no modern tool does. Thanks